# How can I run a terminal command from a program?

Tags: ruby, windows, url, web, terminal

I have a small ruby program that I'm working on at the moment (Pure ruby, not rails), which crawls a small portion of the web for certain movies. Is there a recommended way to, for example, when I run the script from my windows terminal, that it will open up a browser with the url that I extracted?

I know `start http://example.com` works from the windows terminal but im just wondering if there's a way to invoke a method like this directly from a ruby script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a nice gem called launchy to do this (at least opening a url)

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/launchy/2.4.3

In the terminal :

```
gem install launchy
```

then:

```
require 'launchy'
Launchy.open("url")
```